# xslt 1.0 groupping by node attribute(s) and output as html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I've searched stackoverflow for this, but somehow did not find an example that fit me. I am not particularly skilled when it comes to xslt. I want to transform given XML:

```
<ROOT>
    <LIST id="1" name="list1">
        <ITEM rowNumber="1" data="list1row1" name="firstRow">
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM rowNumber="2" data="list1row2" name="secondRow">
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM rowNumber="3" data="list1row3" name="thirdRow">
        </ITEM>
    </LIST>
    <LIST id="2" name="list2">
        <ITEM rowNumber="1" data="list2row1" name="firstRow">
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM rowNumber="2" data="list2row2" name="secondRow">
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM rowNumber="3" data="list2row3" name="thirdRow">
        </ITEM>
    </LIST>
    <LIST id="3" name="list3">
        <ITEM rowNumber="1" data="list3row1" name="firstRow">
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM rowNumber="2" data="list3row2" name="secondRow">
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM rowNumber="3" data="list3row3" name="thirdRow">
        </ITEM>
    </LIST>
</ROOT>
```

Into this HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>firstRow</td>
        <td id="list1_row1">list1row1</td>          
        <td id="list2_row1">list2row1</td>          
        <td id="list3_row1">list3row1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>secondRow</td>
        <td id="list1_row2">list1row2</td>          
        <td id="list2_row2">list2row2</td>          
        <td id="list3_row2">list3row2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>thirdRow</td>
        <td id="list1_row3">list1row3</td>          
        <td id="list2_row3">list2row3</td>          
        <td id="list3_row3">list3row3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I want to take all rows and group them together in a table row, with cells containing the row number, name and data. It is ok if rowNumber and name are hidden cells.

I was thinking of using `<xsl:if test="position() = 1">` to check whether to display metadata (row number and name). Cells would have ID from list name (or id) and row number (so they can be searched by with javascript).

Thank you for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each LIST has exactly the same number of ITEMS (i.e. rows), try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-row" match="ITEM" use="@rowNumber"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
       <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/LIST[1]/ITEM">
           <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@rowNumber"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('item-by-row', @rowNumber)">
                    <td id="{../@name}_row{@rowNumber}"><xsl:value-of select="@data"/></td>    
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: works like a charm. thank you sir! I also used http://www.xsltcake.com/ to help me further modify this example to my case.